# AWS AmazonEC2Client Specify multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using aws java sdk  . I want to access information from multiple EC2 regions .
There is a setRegion(RegionID) method available  but it sets only one region .
Is it possible to set multiple regions and get information from them  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the default end-point to view the information of the service from other region apart from the default region one specified. In other words you may specify the regional end-point every time i.e. **call the service - get the info; change the endpoint and call the service again.**

I have taken SQS as the explain the process.

**Step 1** : Default end point already specified

**Step 2** : Call the web service, get the info about the SQS - Service

**Step 3** : Change the endpoint using the function **[setRegion(Region region)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQS.html#setRegion%28com.amazonaws.regions.Region%29)**

**Step 4** : Call the web service, get the info about the SQS - Service

PS :

1. You can alternatively use **[setEndpoint(String endpoint)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQS.html#setEndpoint%28java.lang.String%29)** with the native - endpoint service URL [ **sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com** ]
2. The similar setRegion and setEndPoint exists for other Services like SNS, RDS etc.